# Using Kmeans to cluster small phrases in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, pyspark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I am having a list of words/phrases(around a million) that I would like to cluster. I am assuming that its the following list:

```
a_list = [u'java',u'javascript',u'python dev',u'pyspark',u'c ++']
a_list_rdd = sc.parallelize(a_list)
```

and I follow this procedure:

Using a string distance(lets say jaro winkler metric) i compute all the distance between the list of the words which will create a matrix of 5x5 with the diagonal being ones, as it computes the distances between itself. And to compute all the distances I broadcast the whole list. So:

```
a_list_rdd_broadcasted = sc.broadcast(a_list_rdd.collect())
```

and the string distances computations:

```
import jaro
def ComputeStringDistance(phrase,phrase_list_broadcasted):
     keyvalueDistances = []
     for value in phrase_list_broadcasted:
         distanceValue = jaro.jaro_winkler_metric(phrase,value)
         keyvalueDistances.append(distanceValue)
     return (array(keyvalueDistances))

string_distances = (a_list_rdd
                             .map(lambda phrase:ComputeStringDistance(phrase,a_list_rdd_broadcasted.value))
                    )
```

and using K means for clustering:

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import KMeans, KMeansModel
clusters = KMeans.train(string_distances, 3 , maxIterations=10,
    runs=10, initializationMode="random")
PredictGroup = string_distances.map(lambda point:clusters.predict(point)).zip(a_list_rdd)
```

and the results:

```
PredictGroup.collect()

ut[73]: 
[(0, u'java'),
 (0, u'javascript'),
 (2, u'python'),
 (2, u'pyspark'),
 (1, u'c ++')]
```

not bad! But what happens if I have 1 million observations and an estimation of around 10000 clusters? Reading some posts large number of clusters is really expensive. Is there a way to overpass this issue?

Answer (score 2):

k-means foes *not* operate on a distance matrix (distance matrixes also do not scale).

K-means also does *not* work with arbitrary distance functions.

It's about minimizing *variance*, the sum-of-squared-deviations-from-the-mean.

What you are doing works because it's halfway to spectral clustering, but it's neither k-means used correctly, nor spectral clustering.

Comment: U mean that I shouldn't use Kmean for that task? What are the alternatives? I have done the same task using hierarchical clustering in the string distances by using R but as far as I know pyspark and mllib doesn't support it.

Comment: hierarchical clustering *does* work on distance matrixes, and can support other distances, so it *is* a better choice for such data, yes. k-means is only correct to use if your input data is a vector field.